# Multiple sql queries in one connection using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make different queries in a single db connection but I can't find the way.
The query is in function of the wery from the results before.
This is the code:

```
String query_disco="SELECT * FROM disco";
    String name = "";
    String adress="";
    String web="";
    int disco_id=0;

    String query_disco_var="SELECT * FROM disco_var";
    float price=0;
    String style="";
    String hin="";
    String hout="";
    String party_name="";
    int day=0;

    String docType="";
    String docTable="";
    String docBody="";

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     

    try {

        DAO a= new DAO();
        ResultSet b =a.executarSQL(query_disco);            
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        docType ="<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC\"--â€?//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0       " +"Transitional//EN\">\n";
        docBody =
                "<HTML>\n"+
                "<HEAD><TITLE>HelloWorld!</TITLE></HEAD>\n"+
                "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n"+
                "<H1>Disco</H1>\n"+
                "<table border=1>"+
                "<tr> <th> name </th> <th> adress </th> <th> web </th> <th> price </th>" +
                "<th> style </th> <th> horari </th> <th> party name </th> </tr>";


        while(b.next()){

            disco_id=b.getInt("disco_id");
            name=b.getString("name");
            adress=b.getString("adress");               
            web=b.getString("web");             

            query_disco_var = query_disco_var + " WHERE disco_id = " + disco_id + " AND day = " + day;
            DAO d= new DAO();
            ResultSet c = d.executarSQL(query_disco_var);
            price=c.getFloat("price");
            style=c.getString("style");
            hin=c.getString("hin");
            hout=c.getString("hout");
            party_name=c.getString("party_name");

            docTable = docTable + "<tr> <td> "+name+" </td> <td> "+adress+" </td> <th>" +web+ "</td> </tr>"+
                       price+ "</td> <td>" +style+ "</td> <td>" +hin+ "-" +hout+ "</td> <td>" +party_name+ "</td> </tr>";
            query_disco_var="SELECT * FROM disco_var";

        } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println(docType+docBody+docTable+
            "</table>" +
            "</BODY></HTML>");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

The connection with de db works right with this script:

```
public class DAO {
private Connection connexio;
private Statement sentencia;
/**
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
public DAO() throws Exception {
    String user="trmcfunt";
    String password="44445555";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connexio=
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/iguanaparty_db_test?user="+user+"&password="+password); 
        sentencia=connexio.createStatement();
}
/**
 * 
 * @param query
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public ResultSet executarSQL(String query)throws SQLException{
    return sentencia.executeQuery(query);
}

/**
 * 
 * @throws SQLException
 */

public void desconnectarBD() throws SQLException {
sentencia.close();
connexio.close();
}
```

}

An I'm getting this exepcions:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:854)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5772)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5692)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getFloat(ResultSetImpl.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getFloat(ResultSetImpl.java:2635)
at controllers.HelloWorld.doGet(HelloWorld.java:87)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

```
ResultSet c = d.executarSQL(query_disco_var);
price = c.getFloat("price");
```

Before getting values from a result set, you must call next(), to place the cursor on the first row. Otherwise, as mentioned in the exception, you're before the start of the result set:

```
ResultSet c = d.executarSQL(query_disco_var);
if (c.next()) {
    price = c.getFloat("price");
```

Also, learn about [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), because passing parameters to a query by concatenating them makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, ad will simply break as soon as, for example, one of the string parameters contains a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ResultSet c` is never moved to the first result (if any). You should wrap your code reading from c with something like

```
if (c.next()) {
  // your original code here
} else {
  // whatever you want to do in this case
}
```

Also, you might have to think about what to do if multiple results are found.

Answer (score 0):

After you execute any SQL the cursor is positioned **before** the first row. That's why you are getting the execpetion, since there is no data available.

Try a `c.next();` after you executed the second SQL query. This will position the cursor on the first result. Remember, if there is no data returned, this call will return `false` and any subsequent extraction of columns will fail, so you should catch this.